# how to create a 2D array in z axis

Tags: python, gnuplot

Is there any equivalent code to `pm3d` and `splot` used in GNU plot ?
I tried `contourf.plot` for my data set which is in the following order:

```
x y z
2.3 0   10000000
2.3 0.5 128484
2.3 1   3456534
2.3 1.5 5600000
.
.
2.31    0   10000000
2.31    0.5 2000568
2.31    1   1500
```

Then it says `z` must be a 2D array. How would I make it an array ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

you need to leave an empty line between each block of constant x (in your case) it's called "gridded data" :

```
2.3 0.5 128484
2.3 1   3456534
2.3 1.5 5600000

2.31    0   10000000
2.31    0.5 2000568
2.31    1   1500

2.5    0   10000000
2.5    0.5 2000568
2.5    1   1500
```

than you can turn on contours something like this

```
set contour
set cntrparams levels discrete 5000,1000000
unset surface
set pm3d implicit
splot 'data' w lines
```